# Getting "No valid copy constructor" in C++ on return struct

Tags: c++, struct, constants, copy-constructor

I'm currently working on implementing a simple 2D vector class `Vector2f` in C++ using Visual Studio Community Edition 2019.

When I try to return a newly constructed one in a method, such as:

```
return Vector2f((this->x/sum),(this->y/sum);
```

I'm getting a hint:

> no suitable copy constructor for Vector2f

and an on-compile error:

> 'return': cannot convert from 'Vector2f' to 'Vector2f'

I've rewritten the class from scratch a few times, and still seem to be getting the error. I don't understand, what exactly is going wrong?

Vector2f_struct.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef PMP_VECTOR2F_STRUCT__H
#define PMP_VECTOR2F_STRUCT__H

namespace pmp
{
    struct Vector2f
    {
        /* Elements */
        float x;
        float y;

        /* Methods */

        // Constructors & Destructor
        Vector2f();
        Vector2f(float i, float j);
        Vector2f(Vector2f& og);
        virtual ~Vector2f();

        // Unary Operators
        float magnitude();
        Vector2f normal();
    };
};

#endif
```

Vector2f_struct.cpp

```
#include "pmp_Vector2f_struct.h"

#ifndef PMP_VECTOR2F_STRUCT__CPP
#define PMP_VECTOR2F_STRUCT__CPP

/* Dependencies */
#include <math.h>

namespace pmp
{
    Vector2f::Vector2f()
    {
        this->x = 0.0f;
        this->y = 0.0f;
        return;
    };

    Vector2f::Vector2f(float i, float j)
    {
        this->x = i;
        this->y = j;
        return;
    };

    Vector2f::Vector2f( Vector2f& og )
    {
        this->x = og.x;
        this->y = og.y;
        return;
    };

    Vector2f::~Vector2f()
    {
        this->x = 0.0f;
        this->y = 0.0f;
        return;
    };

    float Vector2f::magnitude()
    {
        float c2 = (this->x * this->x) + (this->y * this->y);
        return sqrt(c2);
    };

    Vector2f Vector2f::normal()
    {
        float sum = this->x + this->y;
        return Vector2f(this->x / sum, this->y / sum); // Error here.
    };

};

#endif
```

Comment: You return a temporary object, r-value can not be bound to Vector2f&, but can be bound to const Vector2f&. [Copy constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: Yeah, you don't have a valid copy constructor because you forgot the `const` qualifier for the argument.  Look up examples of copy constructors online.

Comment: Furthermore, there's no reason to define a copy constructor yourself since the default one provided by the compiler should do the same thing as yours.  Your destructor is also unneeded.

Comment: Get rid of `Vector2f(Vector2f& og);`, you don't need it. Most likely you don't need the destructor too, unless you really need it to be virtual. In that case, I'd define it as `virtual ~Vector2f() {}`. Zeroing numbers inside doesn't make much sense, and might be optimized away.

Comment: Ah, thank you all! I forgot all about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter of the copy constructor has a non-constant referenced type

```
Vector2f(Vector2f& og);
```

In the member function normal there is returned a temporary object that is copied. You may not bind a temporary object with a non-constant lvalue reference.

Redeclare the copy constructor like

```
Vector2f(const Vector2f& og);
```

Or just remove its explicit declaration. In this case the compiler generates it for you.

Pay attention to that return statements in the constructors and the destructor are redundant.